# Right way or difference between using setState and streamBuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know, when we should should use streamBuilder and when we should use setState method. Should we use only one way in the project for one code style or we can use are both ways. 
For example, we have radio buttons. We can handle it and to redraw after changing radio button via streamBuilder and via setState, but what way is more useful?